# Java SpringBoot Webflux: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record:

Tags: java, spring-webflux

Small question regarding Spring Webflux and Java, reproducible among any 2.x+ versions.

I see often in my logs, exceptions like:

```
Failed to select the application-level protocol:
io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 1201003400000000000015000601001b000102001c000c0300280004ff080001550000004d5353514c3365727665720078080000
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1216) ~[netty-handler-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
```

```
TLS handshake failed:
io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 006a0000010000000136012c000008007fff7f08000000010020003a0000000000000000000000000000000034e600000001000000000000000028434f4e4e4543545f444154413d28434f4d4d414e443d56455253494f4e2929
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1216) ~[netty-handler-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
```

I was wondering, what is the meaning of the part after "not an SSL/TLS record" please?
The long piece of gibberish "12010034000000[...] 006a0000010000[...]"

Thank you

Comment: It's [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). 4d5353514c336572766572 is the (ASCII) characters 'MSSQL3erver' which is almost certainly an MSSQL client, and 28434f4e4e4543545f444154413d28434f4d4d414e443d56455253494f4e2929 is '(CONNECT_DATA=(COMMAND=VERSION))' which looks to me like an Oracle client.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I am getting same error with a different message. Can you give me a reason behind this error.

Comment: @KavinduRavishka: something is trying to connect to your SSL/TLS port using a protocol other than SSL/TLS. In the examples given it was (probably) database clients misconfigured to talk to the wrong host/port. With different data it's probably something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `dave_thompson_085` mentioned, verified it is the **hexadecimal** string representation of the client.

All credits to him (I wish I could just accept his comment as answer).

This was particularly helpful as we could identify some clients performing some attacks. Thanks a lot